# SQL - SUM the values from a COLUMN and put each value in a SEPARATE column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple join query for multiple tables that looks like this:

```
select
  b.buyer_id,
  v.vendor_id,
  r.report_number,
  sum(r.amount_fee),
  f.fee_description
from buyer b
join vendor v on v.vendor_id = bu.vendor_id
join report r on r.report_num = bu.report_num
join fees f on f.report_num = r.report_num
group by b.buyer_id, v.vendor_id, r.report_number, f.fee_description
```

Which will show something like this:
[image]

But I want it to look like this: [image]

Can you help me how to rewrite my script please?

Thanks alot!

Comment: What type of SQL are you using? You need a pivot type calculation which depends on what type of SQL.

Comment: Hello, I am using SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fee descriptions are fixed, a [simple `PIVOT` query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) will do the trick.

```
SELECT
    buyer_id,
    vendor_id,
    report_number,
    [Late Charge], 
    [Finance Charge], 
    [Reserve Fee], 
    [Additional Fee]
FROM
(
    select b.buyer_id, v.vendor_id, r.report_number, r.amount_fee As AmountFee, f.fee_description 
    from buyer b
    join vendor v on v.vendor_id = bu.vendor_id
    join report r on r.report_num = bu.report_num
    join fees f on f.report_num = r.report_num
) As s
PIVOT
(
    Sum(AmountFee) FOR fee_description IN ([Late Charge], [Finance Charge], [Reserve Fee], [Additional Fee])
) As P
```

If the fee descriptions could change, you'll need a dynamic pivot query:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max);
SET @columns = STUFF
(
    (SELECT DISTINCT N',' + QUOTENAME(fee_description)
     FROM fees
     ORDER BY fee_description
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
    .value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
   1, 1, N''
);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'SELECT buyer_id, vendor_id, report_number, ' + @columns + N'
FROM 
(
    select b.buyer_id, v.vendor_id, r.report_number, r.amount_fee As AmountFee, f.fee_description 
    from buyer b
    join vendor v on v.vendor_id = bu.vendor_id
    join report r on r.report_num = bu.report_num
    join fees f on f.report_num = r.report_num
) As s
PIVOT
(
    Sum(AmountFee) FOR fee_description IN (' + @columns + N')
) As P';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Richard Deeming! I just need to put an alias in the end of the pivot and it worked perfectly.. really appreciate it!